# Access Azure CosmosDB Emulator Data Explorer on Mac OS

Tags: java-8, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to CosmosDB. I am using MacOs. According to official document I have installed Windows 10 on VirtualBox and install Azure CosmosDB Emulator. I have started Emulator by using following command -

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /GenKeyFile=cosmosdbauthkey
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /AllowNetworkAccess /KeyFile=cosmosdbauthkey
```

Emulator is started successfully and I am able to access Data Explorer from Virtual Windows Browser.

But by using IPv4 address of Virtual Windows Machine I am not able to access Emulator Data Explorer on Mac Browser.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Am I missing any step for emulator setup. How I can access CosmosDB Emulator Data Explorer from Mac Browser and eventually, Emulator Connection in my Java application which is running on Mac OS.

Comment: can you add the connection string in the question

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I have not tried with my Java Application before that I am trying to access `https://10.0.2.15:8081/_explorer/index.html` from my Mac Browser which I am not able to access.

Answer (score 3):

Currently Cosmosdb Emulator supports only on windows, there is a [*user voice*](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/18533509-add-documentdb-emulator-support-for-mac-os-x-and) added and soon it will be supported for MAC OS as well.

UPDATE:

With the latest Build Announcement, It is supported on [MAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#run-on-linux-macos) as well

Answer (score 0):

I added the steps to get the Azure CosmosDB emulator on a Mac here on this question on StackOverflow:

[Cosmos DB emulator installation on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191130/cosmos-db-emulator-installation-on-mac)