# Cosmos DB emulator installation on Mac

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

```
ipaddr="`ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1`"

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator

docker run \
    --publish 8081:8081 \
    --publish 10250-10255:10250-10255 \
    --memory 3g --cpus=2.0 \
    --name=test-linux-emulator1 \
    --env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_PARTITION_COUNT=10 \
    --env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_DATA_PERSISTENCE=true \
    --env AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS_OVERRIDE=$ipaddr \
    --interactive \
    --tty \
    mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
```

I followed these steps but getting this error

```
./cosmosdb-emulator: ERROR: Invalid mapping of address 0x40037db000 in reserved address space below 0x400000000000. Possible causes:
1) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) starts-up its own running environment sets the stack size limit to unlimited via syscall setrlimit(2);
2) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) adjusts its own execution domain and flag the system its legacy personality via syscall personality(2);
3) sysadmin deliberately sets the system to run on legacy VA layout mode by adjusting a sysctl knob vm.legacy_va_layout.
```

Mac Chip: Apple M1 Pro

Comment: i have got the same issue - seems they still didn't build a new image for arm v8

Answer (score 6):

From the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/docker-emulator-linux?tabs=sql-api%2Cssl-netstd21#run-the-linux-emulator-on-macos),

> The emulator only supports MacBooks with Intel processors.

The Apple M1 Pro you are using is not supported by the emulator.

[The MS team are more than aware of the growing extent
of the problem that poses](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/54#issuecomment-1399067365)

Comment: This emulator only supports intel processors, Microsoft didn't given support for silicon chips